# How to connect to a Windows machine via SSH in graphical mode?

Tags: linux, windows, ssh, gui

I'm on my GNU/Linux computer and I want to connect to a Windows 10 machine with SSH and be able to open different programs (Firefox or Thunderbird for example) in graphical mode (with a GUI, in a window I mean).

I know when connecting to a Linux machine we can use the `ssh -X` option, but what about Windows ?

Thank you.

Comment: Can you say more about the constraints?  E.g. why ssh and not rdesktop, and what are your needs around security?

Comment: My only constraint is that I am on a GNU/Linux machine and want to connect on a Windows machine with SSH. I haven't tried rdesktop but I already configured a working VNC connection. I just want other way to do it in case of need. So I'm trying to use SSH for now. And I haven't any particular needs in term of security, just a minimum secured thing.